# Sample jersey web project for Glassfish 3.1 using maven

Tags: jersey, glassfish-3

Does anyone know of a simple project for glassfish (a webbapp) that is a rest web service using Jersey. If its done in Maven 2 that would be even better! I'm using glassfish 3.1.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the jersey source, there is a samples folder: 
https://svn.java.net/svn/jersey~svn/tags/jersey-1.11-b04/jersey/samples/

Another thing you could try out would be one of the maven-jersey archetypes:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/giqdq/index.html

Comment: just FYI - 1.11 is already out, so you should use that version (or 1.12-SNAPSHOT, if you like "living on the edge" :)

Comment: I tried to generate a project using the archetypes and it got errors.